# SqlDependency performance

Tags: sql-server, triggers, polling, sqldependency, sqlperformance

I have a web application that use a SQL Server database that is shared with others web applications (over which I have no control). I must know when any of the web apps makes changes to some tables in the database.

My first idea was to use `SqlDependency` (specifically [`SqlTableDependency`](https://tabledependency.codeplex.com/), because I need to know the changed data), but I'm concerned about performance problems.

I want to know if there is any performance comparison over `SqlDependency` (not `SqlTableDependency`), triggers (that fires WS, exe, etc.), and polling.

I found some questions and articles, but they are not clear enough to me

- [Using SQLDependency vs. periodic polling of a table (performance impact)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203704/using-sqldependency-vs-periodic-polling-of-a-table-performance-impact)
- [.NET SqlDependency with many notifications vs. high rate polling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660825/net-sqldependency-with-many-notifications-vs-high-rate-polling)
- [How efficient SqlDependency (Service Broker) is compared to query by timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535356/how-efficient-sqldependency-service-broker-is-compared-to-query-by-timer)
- [SqlDependency vs constant polling of a SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269063/sqldependency-vs-constant-polling-of-a-sql-server-database)
- [Design consideration for data retrieval : pooling vs SqlDependency and SqlCacheDependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833741/design-consideration-for-data-retrieval-pooling-vs-sqldependency-and-sqlcached)
- [Query Notification & Service Broker](http://sylvester-lee.blogspot.com.uy/2013/05/query-notification-service-broker.html)

Other info:

- Five tables to monitor
- About 1 change per second on each table
- Tables grow about 100 rows per day

Thank you!

Comment: Note: If you're planning on using SqlDependency with SQL Azure it won't work unless you have your own managed instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640879

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is...there may be too many moving pieces to directly compare performance prior to implementation.  I will speak on performance but also at play here is determining which options satisfy the basic demands of our application.

---

#### SqlDependency vs. SqlTableDependency and Triggers

Though [`SqlDependency`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`SqlTableDependency`](https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency) are similar in name, the behavior and results of implementing either are so very different.  Unlike `SqlDependency`, `SqlTableDependency` supplements the Queue with other database objects, namely a Trigger on the targeted table.

In my application, which handles `SignalR` messaging from server to client, `SqlDependency` is a **non-starter** because on its own it does not give me the real-time data I need to read from the db changes.  In all fairness, it was not designed this way.  Any data would be procured from a seperate db call.  So any efficiencies or perceived speed are practically nullified.  If data is changing frequently enough, and without enough workarounds, calling a procedure immediately after a change notification may not even bring back the data we are looking for.

Brick walls such as these led me to implement `SqlTableDependency`.  What may not be instantly clear from the documentation is that `SqlTableDependency` automatically populates database objects on Start().  So we do not have to spend time authoring Sql procs.  The main disclaimer here is that not only does your DBA have to be onboard with setting the DB broker enabled, but also permissions to create and remove triggers.  One must be careful to Stop() a `SqlTableDependency` or the triggers will have to be manually cleared from the db.  If you want to guarantee poor performance, leave dozens of triggers on a table!  Not only will your notifications take longer, but anyone querying the table for data will experience slowdowns.

That being said, **we only need one** `SqlTableDependency` trigger to send messages to thousands of clients or send the data to as many services as necessary.  From that perspective, I would qualify it as efficient.

Here is a brief mention on performance from the `SqlTableDependency` documentation:

> **Load Test and Performance**
> SqlTableDependency support notifications triggered by DML executed every 50 milliseconds. Test realized with two client applications concurrently executing 10.000 random insert/update/operation on same table.(https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency)

---

#### Polling

One could set up a service to poll each of the 5 tables to monitor. However, depending on whether we need to handle the data within each change or whether we simply need to know that something changed,  I would estimate handling the data from polling would get cumbersome with such a severe frequency (by your estimate 1 per second).

---

#### Recommendation

Create as many varities of implementations as time allows and observe the behavior of each.  Some will rule themselves out prior to any load testing.  `SqlTableDependency` is a solid place to begin.

With each approach comes a unique implementation, and thus performance barometers must address how the supporting code and data environments factor into the overall picture.

[sqldependency](/questions/tagged/sqldependency)[signalr](/questions/tagged/signalr)[sqltabledependency](/questions/tagged/sqltabledependency)[triggers](/questions/tagged/triggers)[polling](/questions/tagged/polling)[sqlperformance](/questions/tagged/sqlperformance)

Comment: If I have a table with 1M rows, this system will retrieve all 1M rows to be able to track data changes of that table, am I right?

Comment: @vpetrovic no it just creates database triggers that watch for any changes. The source code for SqlTableDependency might help https://github.com/canadelinc/sqltabledependency/blob/master/TableDependency.SqlClient/SqlTableDependency.cs

Comment: Also note that SqlTableDependency (not by MS) does not internally even use Microsoft's SqlDependency. I kind of expected it to but searching in github shows not a single usage of it.

Comment: Where does SQL Server keep the trigger(s) created for SqlTableDependency?

Answer (score 5):

as correctly told by MTADEV "*That being said, we only need one SqlTableDependency trigger to send messages to thousands of clients or send the data to as many services as necessary. From that perspective, I would qualify it as efficient.*".

When you need to send notification change on multiple client, you have to create a central service that hold SqlTableDependency. Every notification delivered by SqlTableDependency will be managed by this service that, in turn, will notify other clients:

[image]

Please have a look at: https://stockprices.codeplex.com/

Comment: Is there a way to tell SqlTableDependency to use the existing trigger and queue for all clients.? My experience is that each SqlDependency client uses a new Trigger which is a performance hell.

Comment: I mean ofcourse without a central service